# Proper way to refresh multiple tab in backround thread

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have implemented dynamic tab navigation with fragments. Fragments are stored on the stack and when user change tab, new fragment should replace existing content to show new items.
But first, data must be refreshed (they will be downloading from rest webservice) and it takese some time, so there is also BusyFragment, indicating data loading process.

I implemented background refreshing data with AsyncTask and I have separate AsyncTask object that is called to refresh specific tabs, this way:

```
private void RefreshShopsMainMenuFragment(Fragment f)
    {


        if (refreshAsyncTaskShops != null && refreshAsyncTaskShops.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
            return;

        final ListFragment fragmentToRefresh = (ListFragment) f;


        refreshAsyncTaskShops = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ListDataDef>>()
        {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                ShowBusyFragment(true, Global.TAB_SHOPS); //for other tabs, other tab identifiers from Global
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<ListDataDef> doInBackground(Void... voids)
            {
                return ShopsTabDataProvider.GetNewData(); //For other tabs, different data provider call
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ListDataDef> result)
            {
                fragmentToRefresh.mainData = result;
                fragmentToRefresh.DisplayNewData();

                ShowBusyFragment(false, Global.TAB_SHOPS); //for other tabs, different tab indentifier
            }
        };

        refreshAsyncTaskShops.execute();

    }
```

So, basically as shown above: to refresh shops tab, refreshAsyncTaskShops will be called, there are also other async task object, I marked lines where they are different.

Is there any more elegant solution, without declaring multiple AsyncTask objects? I'm not fully satisfied with my current implementation, because my all async tasks objects are basically the same.

Also, as you can see, there is no any queue so don't need to wait for first tab refreshing and to refresh another one. However, refreshing the same tab multiple times simultaneously should never happen so I added if condition to prevent the same task to be executed if previous one is not finished yet.

Comment: Are you using view pager and floating tabs ?

Comment: TabHost and OnTabChangeListener